# Trying to get borders to my python turtle module game

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am trying to make this game where once you hit the borders of the box the turtle will return to the position it was at directly before it hit the border of the box. I am pretty new so any help would be appreciated. So far I have if y cord is greater than the box it goes back to right before it hit but it doesn't seem to be working.

```py
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('black')
line = turtle.Turtle()

line.goto(-450,-15)
line.speed(9999)
line.pendown
line.color('white')
line.forward(850)
line.left(90)
line.forward(400)
line.left(90)
line.forward(850)
line.left(90)
line.forward(410)
line.color('black')


fred = turtle.Turtle()
fred.penup()
fred.goto(-430, 0)
fred.shape('square')
fred.color('white')
fred.penup()
fred.delay = 0.1
fred.direction = "Stop"


#Set Up (Controls)
wn.listen()


def ahead():
    fred.forward(10)


def behind():
    fred.backward(10)


if fred.ycor() < -500:
    fred.goto(0, -500)

if fred.ycor() > 500:
    fred.goto(0, 500)


wn.onkey(behind,"a")
wn.onkey(ahead,"d")
wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: `Turtle` is nice for drawing figures but not for creating game. It may need to access `tkinter` functions to detect collisions. OR you would have to write own function which checks `ycor()` `xcor()` with box coordinates (and this need to put them manually in code) and use `forward/backward` to move back. And you have to do it inside `ahead()` and `behind()` - so your `if fred.ycor() ...` seems useless.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `if` inside functions - and values in `if` you may have to calculate manually.

```
def ahead():
    fred.forward(10)
    #print(fred.xcor())

    if fred.xcor() > 430 - 50: # minus turtle width
        fred.backward(10)

def behind():
    fred.backward(10)
    #print(fred.xcor())

    if fred.xcor() < -430 :
        fred.forward(10)
```

But problem will be if you will have more elements which should stop turtle.

`turtle` doesn't have function to detect collisions and you may have to access `tkinter` functions for this or you would have to create own function which checks `xcor`, `ycor` with coordinates from some list. And list should have coordinates for all objects. And this may need to calculate coordinates manually.

---

`turtle` is nice for drawing figures but not for games. There are better modules - like [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/), [Arcade](https://api.arcade.academy/en/latest/), [PGzero](https://codewith.mu/en/tutorials/1.0/pgzero) (`PyGame Zero`)